# How to embed Python interpreter in C program that is compiled against another Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I have a Python 3.8 embedded in C program (compiled and linked against 3.8). How can I make possible that this C code embed Python 3.10 and 3.11 without changing targeting 3.8 while compiling?

I was playing with something like:

```
PyConfig config;
PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);

config.program_name = L"python3";
config.pythonpath_env = L"???";
config.base_exec_prefix = L"???";
config.base_executable = L"???";
config.base_prefix = L"???";
config.exec_prefix = L"???";
config.executable = L"???";

PyConfig_Read(&config);
config.module_search_paths_set = 1;
PyWideStringList_Append(&config.module_search_paths, L"/usr/lib/python310.zip:/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload");

Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
PyRun_SimpleString(
    "import os\n"
    "print(os.sys.path)\n"
);

Py_Finalize();
```

Depending on `config` parameters, I would expect to see output for 3.10 or 3.11. I've read the docs, but did not get it :(

Kindest regards

Comment: The Python C API is meant for embedding a single Python interpreter version into a C application. To support multiple Python versions, you would typically compile separate versions of your application for each version and distribute those. Switching Python versions at runtime in the same process is not supported.

Comment: I was afraid of this: unfortunately we have an app that is compiled against older Python version and it's not possible to compile it against newer without significant effort.

Comment: @SyntaxNavigator I would accept this as an answer - if you'd like to post is as an answer